# Discord is the application that gives an automatic role if it is authorized in the authorized application

Tags: javascript

If the process is successful after verifying,
I want it to give an automatic role, how can I do it?

Bu kodda onay yapıldıktan sonra rol verilmesini istiyorum fakat yapamıyorum
nasıl yapabilirim yardımcı olursanız sevinirim.

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
const users = require('../../models/users');
const epic = require("../../epic")

module.exports = {
  name: "btn",
  description: "Sends Button",
  default_permission: true,
  timeout: 3000,
  category: "whitelist",
  userPerms: ["SEND_MESSAGES"],
  ownerOnly: false,

  run: async (client, interaction, args) => {

    const row = new discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(
      new discord.MessageButton()
        .setStyle('LINK')
        .setURL(`${epic.authLink}`)
        .setLabel(`${epic.btn}`),
    )
    interaction.deferReply();
    interaction.deleteReply();

    interaction.channel.send({ components: [row] })

  }
}
```